# mysql into table alternating <td>

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I have a table which is being populated using mysql

```
<?php $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM itemList"); ?>

<table>
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){ ?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $row['item'] . ": <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cart[]\"
      value=\"" . $row['item'] . "\">";?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo $row['item'] . ": <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cart[]\" 
value=\"" . $row['item'] . "\">";?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php 
} ?>
</table>
```

Currently this code loops the same data into both column in the table. How would I got about to make the data loop into alternate columns?

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
        item1
     </td>

     <td>
       item2
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      item3
    </td>

    <td>
       item4
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM itemList"); ?>

<table>
<tr>
<?php  $i=1; while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){ ?>

<td>
    <?php echo $row['item'] . ": <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cart[]\"
      value=\"" . $row['item'] . "\">";?>
</td>

<?php if($i%2 == 0){ echo "</tr><tr>";  } ?>

<?php $i++;
} ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Other way as per  `@OlivierH` comments on my above anwser

```
<?php 
$rows = array(); while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 $rows[] = $row;
} 
?>

<table>
<?php $totalrows = count($rows); 
if($totalrows){ ?>
    <tr>
    <?php  $i=1; foreach($totalrows as $r){ ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $r['item'] . ": <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cart[]\"
              value=\"" . $r['item'] . "\">";?>
        </td>
        <?php if($i%2 == 0 && $totalrows != $i){ echo "</tr><tr>";  } ?>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: this will work for when you have results and this on you how you are handling this. I just provide a way how to achieve the result.

Comment: I can't believe this kind of answer can be accepted. This code is unreadable, unmaintainable and does not work well since it outputs empty lines. As expected, the OP copied and pasted this code and had his results displaying, perfect. I just hope future visitors will have enough courage to read comments and not take this as an example.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an index counter and modulo operator to check whether that counter is even or uneven. Something like:

```
$i = 1;
while (bla) {
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
       // even number, col 1
    } else {
       // uneven number, col 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a count and play on it :

- For first item, you display `<tr>` and your data
- For second item, you display your data and `</tr>`
- For third item, you display `<tr>` and your data
- ...

You can use `%`(modulo operator). It returns the rest of a division.

Example :

```
echo 0%2; //0
echo 1%2; //1
echo 2%2; //0
echo 3%2; //1
echo 4%2; //0
...
```

You can also just play with a variable that you set to 0, 1, 0 ... alternatively. 
Here is the code :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM itemList"); 
$i = 0;

echo "<table>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
    //create new line if this item is the first of the row (i == 0)
    if($i == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>" . $row['item'] . ": <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cart[]\" value=\"" . $row['item'] . "\"></td>";

    //if the item is the second of the row, close the tr and set i to 0
    if($i == 1){
        echo "</tr>";
        $i = 0;
    }
    //else, increment i 
    else{
        $i++;
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```